# junit testSuite: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am getting follwing error code for running junit target in ant.   EshopCoreTestSuite is a framework as:

```
public class EshopCoreTestSuite extends TestSuite {

    public static Test suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();          
        suite.addTestSuite(CustomerContextTest.class);
        return suite;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         TestRunner.run(EshopCoreTestSuite.class);}  }
```

error:

```
   <error message="com.bgc.EshopCoreTestSuite" type="java.lang.ClassNotFoundException">java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bgc.EshopCoreTestSuite         ....        
        </error>
```

junit target:

```
<property name="COMP_TEST_SRC_DIR" location="test/java"/>
<property name="TEST_BUILD_DIR" location="build/test"/>
<property name="COMP_JAVA_SRC" location="src/java" />
<property name="COMP_BUILD" location="build" />
```

I am just confused here with path. I have src folder and under this java and test folder for java and test files. I hope I have given more/wrong path.
    ....

```
<junit printsummary="on" fork="on">
        <classpath>
        <path refid="CLASSPATH_JUNIT"/>
        <dirset dir="${TEST_SRC_DIR}"/>
        </classpath>
        <env key="app.module" path="ESW"/>
        <env key="app.env" path="DEV"/>
        <test name="com.bgc.EshopCoreTestSuite" todir="../../../BUILD/ESW/ESWBUILD/CI/REPORT" outfile="junit_report">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        </test>
    </junit>
```

Comment: `${TEST_SRC_DIR}` looks suspicious. don't you have a specific variable for compiled class (output or bin) directory?

Comment: i have edited main problem. I am just confused with path element, can you clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
 <dirset dir="${TEST_SRC_DIR}"/>
```

to:

```
 <dirset dir="${TEST_BUILD_DIR}"/>
```

in that `<junit>` section. The classpath must contain built classes, not source files. If your classes are being generated to `.../src/java`, then use `${COMP_JAVA_SRC}` instead. (But that's a bit non-standard.)

The point is that this `dirset` variable must point to the root of where your `.class` files are located.

Comment: hum... where is the `com/bgc/EshopCoreTestSuite.class` file located in your directory structure?

Comment: bgc-esw-core\src\test   and test files under this. bgc-esw-core\src\java, all java files under this package.

Comment: it's the `.class` files you need to be pointing to. are these really in `src\java`?

Comment: sorry, classfiles are located in bgc-esw-core/target/classes/com/bgc/EshopCoreTestSuite.class

Comment: then set a property to that value (target/classes/) if you don't have one already, and use that in the `dirset` value.